# Data is automatically sorted when return from Java to Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, sorting, dwr

I use DWR to load data into a drop-down when another drop-down is changing.
This is the Javascript.

```
ClassX.loadData(StudentId
            function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        );
```

I pass `Map<Integer,String>` from Java to above JavaScript. This Map is sorted on server side with it's value, but when I check the Map in the console above, they are sorted automatically with it's key values.
Is there any way to stop this automatically sorting and retrieve the original values sent from server? What is the reason for this?

Comment: How are you creating your map? What does this map says about its ordening policy?

Comment: @Ferrybig  Map<Integer, String> map= new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>();

Comment: Java Map which is ordered with inserting order.